# Inconsistent visualization of degree intervals on tkiz circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I use the following code in order to draw a circle with numeric labels at specific degree intervals. Variable `\FullLength` (see line 5) hereby allows for user input.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\def \FullLength {160000} % user-input
\FPeval{\BPperDegr}{\FullLength/360}
\FPeval{\DegrperBP}{1/\BPperDegr}
\FPeval{\DegrperTenKBP}{10000/\BPperDegr}

\FPeval{\FirstInterval}{round(\DegrperTenKBP, 2)}
\FPeval{\SecondInterval}{round(\DegrperTenKBP*2, 2)}
\FPeval{\SecondToLastInterval}{round(360-(\DegrperTenKBP*2), 2)}
\FPeval{\LastInterval}{round(360-\DegrperTenKBP, 2)}
\def \CircleIntervals {\FirstInterval,\SecondInterval,...,\SecondToLastInterval,\LastInterval}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
    \draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in \CircleIntervals
    {
        \FPeval{\label}{round(\xi*10000, 0)}
        \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:3.9cm) -- (\angle:4.1cm);
        \node[font=\large] at (\angle:4.75cm) {\label};
    }
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0:3.9cm) -- (0:4.1cm);
    \node[font=\large] at (0:4.75cm) {origin};
    \node[red] at (0:0) {
    \textbf{\FullLength}; \CircleIntervals
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As long as variable `\FullLength` is larger than the integer `159982` (e.g., `160000`), I receive a consistent visualization of the degree intervals.
[image]

Once variable `\FullLength` is equal to or smaller than integer `159982`, however, the visualization of the degree intervals becomes inconsistent.
[image]

The issue obviously rests with how the variable `\CircleIntervals` is constructed, but I cannot identify the correct solution so that any integer specified by the user leads to a consistent visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you say `\foreach ... {\one,\two,...,\penultimate,\last}`, TikZ takes this as the conjunction of `{\one,\two,...,\penultimate}` and `\last`. So `\penultimate` is the upper limit. Only values equal to or less than this value count. Since 314.99 is not 22.50 plus some multiple of 22.51, it just acts as the upper bound. So, there is no step at 314.99 and the next one is 337.50.

I am not really sure what the point of using `fp` rather than PGF maths is here. However, the easiest way to adapt the existing code to do what you want is probably to use 360 as the upper limit and just test to ensure we don't make a second label there.

For example,

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\def \FullLength {159982} % user-input
% \def \FullLength {160000} % user-input
\FPeval{\BPperDegr}{\FullLength/360}
\FPeval{\DegrperBP}{1/\BPperDegr}
\FPeval{\DegrperTenKBP}{10000/\BPperDegr}

\FPeval{\FirstInterval}{round(\DegrperTenKBP, 2)}
\FPeval{\SecondInterval}{round(\DegrperTenKBP*2, 2)}
\FPeval{\SecondToLastInterval}{round(360-(\DegrperTenKBP*2), 2)}
\FPeval{\LastInterval}{round(360-\DegrperTenKBP, 2)}
\def \CircleIntervals {\FirstInterval,\SecondInterval,...,360}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect, line width=3pt]
    \draw[] (0,0) circle [radius=4cm];
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi, evaluate=\angle as \i using int(\angle)] in \CircleIntervals
    {
      \ifnum\i=360\relax\else
        \FPeval{\label}{round(\xi*10000, 0)}
        \draw[line width=1.5pt] (\angle:3.9cm) -- (\angle:4.1cm);
        \node[font=\large] at (\angle:4.75cm) {\label};
      \fi
    }
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0:3.9cm) -- (0:4.1cm);
    \node[font=\large] at (0:4.75cm) {origin};
    \node[red] at (0:0) {
    \textbf{\FullLength}; \CircleIntervals
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the expected result in both cases. If necessary, you could use a `>355` or something rather than `=360` if there are cases which will otherwise come in just within the limit.

Here's the case for the uncommented code as posted above

[image: corrected second case]

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you! -- As for using package `fp` rather than `pgfmath`, I could never get short and succinct code with `pgfmath` (though, admittedly, I don't understand `pgfmath` very well). What, for example, would be the `pdfmath` pendant for `\FPeval{\BPperDegr}{\FullLength/360}`? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl `\pgfmathsetmacro\BPperDegr{\FullLength/360}` ?

Comment: I just mentioned this because it makes things awkward e.g. `evaluate=\angle as \i using int(\angle)` is only there because using `\angle` directly gives me errors. (The `int` is just because evaluating `\angle` using `\angle` will probably introduce a full decimal point thingie otherwise.)